# Android exoplayer video crop inside

Tags: android, video, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am working on the integration of social media video posts in a list and there is a problem with cropping video images.
To avoid blank sides on a composable list item I want to apply similar to an image `ContentScale.Crop` logic.
However, if I apply `RESIZE_MODE_FIT` edges a blank like in a screenshot [image]
and If I apply `RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH` the size of the list element just extends and breaks the whole list, please check the second screenshot, instead of 400px video column takes the height of the video content.

[image]

I've already tried to play with `player.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT` with no success. Could you please help me here?